# Output argument "y" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "N"

Tags: matlab, function, recursion

I am currently working on building a b-spline basis function. This is a recursive function. The function definition is given in the image:

[image: bunch of equations]

It is showing this error:

> Output argument "y" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "N".

How can I fix my code to work correctly?

```
function y = N(k,i,t,m)

    %k is the order 
    %i is the pointer for the control point 
    %t (knot value) is the parameter used for defining a point on the curve
    %m is the knot vector

    % for the knot value t to be in between the ti and ti+k

    if t < m(1,i+k+1)
        if t > m(1,i+1)
           if k == 1
               y = 1;
           end
           for h = 2:1:k
               y = ((((t - m(1,i+1))/ (m(1,i+h)- m(1,i+1)))* N(h-1,i,t,m)) + (((m(1,i+h+1) - t)/ (m(1,i+h+1)- m(1,i+2)))* N(h-1,i+1,t,m)));
           end 
        else 
            y = 0;
        end 
    end
end
```

The expected result is it should keep increasing the order of the function k and keep giving me desired output but instead I am receiving this error.

Comment: I am not familiar with how matlab considers variable and statement scopes. Could you properly indent your code so that it reflects the level of if-statements, as an example? Also, indent your code 4 spaces to get it formatted *as* code.

Comment: I suspect that the if-statement with `t < m(...)...` ends with the last `end` on the line with 2 `end` keywords, in which case, what if that expression is false, what is `y` going to be then?

Comment: If this is a correct rendition of the scoping here - https://gist.github.com/lassevk/1a09387ccacf82877b248759b1e97f5d - can you clarify what `y` would be if the if-statement on line 9 evaluates to false?

Comment: The first `if` doesn’t have an `else`. If the condition is not satisfied, `y` remains unassigned.